# Swift SpriteKit/Quartz/Metal: How to draw low-level pixel data at 60FPS?

Tags: swift, metal, quartz, nes

I am working on a NES Emulator project for macOS written in Swift.
However, I'm having a hard time finding a solution to render the internal VRAM into some sort of view in an efficient way.

Simplifying the problem, let's assume I have an array of RGBA pixel values representing my 256x240 pixel screen:

```swift
var viewport: Data = Data(count: width * height * 4 /* one byte each color channel */);
```

My code will directly change the internal pixels of this `viewport` changing individual pixels' color. The goal is to render these pixels 60 times per second, in the most efficient way possible.

**Failed attempts**

So far I tested both SpriteKit, and Quartz but I always face the same issue: the overhead is so large, that the code barely runs at 30FPS, and it's not even doing anything special: just changing pixels' color randomly.

*SpriteKit code*

```swift
let node = SKSpriteNode(color: NSColor.black, size: self.size);

func display() {
  self.node.texture = SKTexture(data: self.pixels, size: self.size);
}
```

*Quartz code*

```swift
// Custom NSView class

override func draw(_ dirtyRect: NSRect) {
  if let context = NSGraphicsContext.current?.cgContext {
    let bitmapInfo = CGBitmapInfo(rawValue: CGImageAlphaInfo.noneSkipLast.rawValue)
    let ctx = CGContext(data: &data,
                        width: width, height: height,
                        bitsPerComponent: 8,
                        bytesPerRow: width * 4,
                        space: CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB(),
                        bitmapInfo: bitmapInfo.rawValue)
     let image = ctx?.makeImage()!
     context.draw(image, in: self.frame);
   }
}
```

**Question**

Is there a better way to implement such functionality? Or are these tools too much high-level for this kind of task?

*PS: I am also looking at GLUT/OpenGL, but I know OpenGL has been deprecated and I'm wondering if there is a new "official" way to code this*

Answer (score 0):

After a day of debugging turns out the actual bottleneck was... Swift itself!
I made a simple command line project to measure the time needed to update an array of 250,000 bytes and the result was a surprise (at least for me).

**Swift took 58ms**. So why this much? The problem is that the XCode debugging build has a terrible overhead I was not expecting: coming from the C++ world, I was expecting the same drop in performance of a Debug build in clang, but that was really not the case.

**Once archived and exported the build, the problem was vastly reduced.**

Final note: I then proceeded to make some tests and compare OpenGL, SpriteKit, and Quartz. The latter was the only framework I could not get the 60fps I was looking for, not even in Release mode.